# Swift 3 Remove objects from an array that are not present in another array and maintaining order

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

Array1 = [Washington, Franklin, Florida, Alaska, California, Georgia]

Array2 = [California, Washington, Georgia]

I want to get

Array1 = [Washington, California, Georgia]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```swift
var array1 = ["Washington", "Franklin", "Florida", "Alaska", "California", "Georgia"]
var array2 = ["California", "Washington", "Georgia"]

let filterArray = array1.filter {
    array2.contains($0)
}
```

The `filterArray` is what you want

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
let filteredArray = array1.filter({Array2.contains($0)})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter for achieving desired output

**Using filter:**

```
let array1 = ["Washington", "Franklin", "Florida", "Alaska", "California", "Georgia"]
let array2 = ["California", "Washington", "Georgia"]

let aryCommonElements = array1.filter { array2.contains($0)}
```

**Output:**

```
["Washington", "California", "Georgia"]
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: He can not use the sets , because he wants to maintain the order

Comment: I have showed two methods. One with set and other with Filter. The filter one will work.

I have edited my answer please check it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve only common elements than use:

**In Swift 3**

```
let Array1 = ["Washington", "Franklin", "Florida", "Alaska", "California", "Georgia"]

let Array2 = ["California", "Washington", "Georgia"]

let common = GetCommonElements(lhs: Array1, rhs: Array2)

print(common)

func GetCommonElements <T, U> (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> [T.Iterator.Element] where T: Sequence, U: Sequence, T.Iterator.Element: Equatable, T.Iterator.Element == U.Iterator.Element {
       var returnArray:[T.Iterator.Element] = []
       for lhsItem in lhs {
           for rhsItem in rhs {
               if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                  returnArray.append(lhsItem)
               }
           }
       }
       return returnArray
}
```